# Using Python convert binary data to bmp image file

Tags: python, image, bmp

Now I have the binary data, but I couldn't use write() function to convert them to bmp file

**Details**

```
f.write(binary_data,"new.bmp")
```

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

In fact, I just want to modify some image data to create a new image. What I just know is,

1. open the image and read it data
2. convert data to binary (because I want to modify some bits data)
3. write data then save

It seems that write(str_data) did work in early python versions. (I referenced others methods about writing data into image.)
And I tried to use **data.encode('hex')**

> LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to
>   handle arbitrary codecs

Are there another ways to modify bit data and then write them to a bmp file?

Comment: Python 3 I guess. There you should have binary data as `bytes` type. Maybe you initialize your data as string. `bytes()` or just `b''` will create an empty `bytes`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I have solved this problem. But **bytes()** didn't work. Because it just return a _byte_. The type of BMP file is a _byte list_. So here should use **bytearray()** :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.
The BMP image file is stored with a byte array. Just use bytearray() function.
My solution is:

```
new_data = []
for i in range(0, len(data), 8):
    new_data.append(data[i:i+8])  # 8 digit binary list
int_data = [] 
for i in new_data:
    int_data.append(int(i,2))  # bytearray will convert decimal to hex
a= bytearray(int_data)
```

Then it can work using write(a)
:>